# Função isset não identifica botão submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Configurei o envio de um formulário através do AJAX. O problema é que a função `isset()` do meu arquivo PHP identifica todos os campos do formulário, menos o botão `submit`. Fiz um teste substituindo o parâmetro de `isset()` pelos campos do `form` e os retornos foram `true`.
Alguém sabe o que há de errado com esse código?

Botão:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar">
```

Ajax:

```
$("#id_formulario").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "Sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Falha";
}
```

Comment: Substitua o input por `<button id="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar">Registrar</button>` e diga se deu certo.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e fornecer um [mcve] do problema em vez de trechos soltos. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site. Precisa ver como está disparando o envio, para ver se o clique do submit está valendo de fato.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas não deu certo César. O que eu resolvi fazer no fim das contas foi verificar se os campos do formulário estão preenchidos já que são poucos.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

o que você está tentando fazer é um gato.

A tag value é inútil nesse caso. O submit serve apenas para "disparar" o formulário causando a ação de POST.

Se você quiser salvar algum parâmetro de forma escondida, crie um input com a tag hidden.